# Android SQLite Table will not store my decimal (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am passing a float type i.e 3.25 to a column in my table which is data type FLOAT(53).  The application works with integers but anytime I put a decimal in, it crashes.

Comment: Please add the crash stacktrace and a minimal piece of code that shows up in there to your question. SQLite is capable of storing floating point numbers just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a float? If you are trying to give it a hard number like 3.25 instead of a variable, 3.25 is actually a double, not a float. To give it an actual float, use 3.25f.

Comment: Yes I am sure.  I passed a variable of type float *sorry for not clarifying*.  I just worked around this problem by receiving the data as text and converting it for future use...